# How to create custom poller in Inbound channel adapter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I want to create a custom poller which poll the data only once and then stop the main thread. Or how can i stop the poller after one poll and exit the application?

Answer (score 0):

For that purpose you need to implement a custom `Trigger` to inject in the mentioned poller.

Something like this:

```
public class OnlyOnceTrigger implements Trigger {

    private final AtomicBoolean hasRun = new AtomicBoolean();

    @Override
    public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext triggerContext) {
        if (this.hasRun.getAndSet(true)) {
            return null;
        }

        return new Date();
    }

}
```

when `nextExecutionTime()` returns `null`, the scheduler stops to run the task, therefore no polling any more after just one run.